# how to get Device UUID in iOS from Beacon broadcasting Devices within a range of region?

Tags: ios, swift, broadcastreceiver, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I want to develop an iOS app that will work as **Beacon** receiver which will  get broadcasted device **UUID's** from  surrounding distance via bluetooth low energy(**BLE**) device supported coverage distance.

I am following this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/152330/ibeacon-tutorial-ios-swift. This tutorial provides a device to work as Beacon via adding Device UUID's, but i need to get those device UUID's automatically.

How can i do that? Is it possible using CoreLocation and CoreBluetooth services?

Comment: On iOS you can only detect beacons for which you know the uuid. It is not possible to listen for all UUIDs.

Comment: Yep, you cannot do this on iOS.  It is worth noting, however, that you can do so on Android, Linux and Windows.

Comment: As far as I know beacon work only as a transmitter. its not gonna receive or watch the devices.